# Connecting two Raspberry Pis two capture synchronized images

Tags: gpio, python, camera

I have two Raspberry Pi 4s and I want to connect them together so I can capture synchronized images; one from each pi. At the moment, I have one pi capturing an image after I press a button that is connected to a gpio pin on the Pi.
Is it possible to send the same signal to the other Pi to obtain another image on the second Pi, such that I don't have to first connect them via ethernet cable?

Comment: Not really a Pi question.  The question reduces to how do I communicate between computers without using a hard wired Ethernet cable.

Comment: This is an XY question. You want to do X have decided Y is the solution and are asking us how to do Y.

Comment: connect the button to both Pis

Comment: @jsotola it is poor advice to suggest connecting 2 Pi GPIO. If done properly with suitable isolation it MAY be a solution.

Comment: like @Milliways said... connecting two GPIOs (high resistance or by a galvanic separated solution) seems the best way, and still then you will have a.) the Jitter and latency of that circuit + b.) you will have an input jitter from the linux operating system. this means, both pictures will at best be taken with several microseconds offset - if not milliseconds. Realtimepaches might improve the issue. maybe pinning your application to a cpu-core also might improve the timing, but with the PI it will never be "good" in terms of a short offset / jitter

Comment: Also I would suggest to trigger both PIs with the same mechanism to take the photo. Even if one is the Master and releasing the trigger, I guess the timing is much better if you seperate this in two theads. One firing the trigger and the other waiting for the trigger and taking the photo. You also might meassure timing with an osciloscope and store offsets (incl. average jitter) in both PI's to improve timing further. (the systems inherent jitter can be compensated with adding more offset, which means if you want taking photos at a certain point in time, you need to trigger earlier!)